# How to know which pages/sites are most used (hit count) for a web application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-analytics, google-analytics

How to get **view count** and **most visited sites** at a web application level as a whole in **SharePoint on premises**.

Other than **Popularity Trends** is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should get to know about **Google Analytics**, Google Analytics is a web analytics service provided by Google and the most interesting part is, it is a freeware. It can be used to track and report the website traffic.

You may get lots of blogs regarding **Google Analytics for SharePoint**. Listed few below,

https://www.harepoint.com/Articles/GoogleAnalyticsSharePoint.aspx
https://zimmergren.net/integrating-the-google-analytics-api-in-sharepoint-in-order-to-enable-users-to-review-analytics-data-directly/
http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-enable-google-analytics-in-sharepoint-2013-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

"Use Google Analytics" is the easy answer to this question.  However...over the past few years Google Analytics has morphed into more of an advertising tracking solution than a web analytics solution, which means it isn't a good choice for SharePoint Intranets.  Plus, GA's Terms of Service doesn't allow you to store usernames in the reports.

http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/sharepoint-and-google-analytics

SharePoint sits on top of IIS, and the IIS web logs contain the information you're looking for. Just find a way to process the IIS logs, and you'll be all set.